# primefaces ajax with listener, update and process attributes, listener method does not executed

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.0.0.M2 library. At this library, `<p:selectOneMenu>` element exists. My problem is that when I use `<p:ajax>` tag with `listener`, `update` and `process` attributes, the listener method does not get invoked, but `update` and `process` works fine. Here is my code:

```html
<h:form prependId="false" id="frmNewRecord">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" style="font-size: 10px;width:840px">
        Öğrenci No <p:inputText value={newRecord.azerKimKayit.ogrenciNo}" maxlength="11">
            <p:ajax event="blur" update="frmNewRecord" listener="#{newRecord.getStudent}" process="frmNewRecord" />
</h:form>
```

And my backing bean is (necassary method) :

```
public void getStudent() {
  azerKimKayit = azerKimKayitBo.findByOgrNo(azerKimKayit.getOgrenciNo());
}
```

Comment: Your code fragment seems incorrect or oversimplified. I don't see a closing `p:input` and `h:panelGrid`.

Comment: I copied only necessary code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in an AjaxBehavior Event in your method:

```
public void getStudent(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
   azerKimKayit = azerKimKayitBo.findByOgrNo(azerKimKayit.getOgrenciNo());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916191/primefaces-ajax-with-listener-update-and-process-attributes-listener-method-do), BalusC suggests adding `@this` to your `process` tag.